# converting xml to Json with lift behaves strange

Tags: xml, json, scala, xml-serialization, lift

I'm using scala / lift for a Rest API. Under the hood I'm generating xml which will be converted to json via Xml.toJson() as output.

Now i noticed some strange behavior which drives me nuts.

for example i have the following xml:

```
<data>
<item>
    <foo>1</foo>
    <bar>1</bar>
</item>
<item>
    <foo>2</foo>
    <bar>2</bar>
</item>
</data>
```

the result of xml.toJson() looks like:

```
JObject(
List(
    JField(
        data,JObject(
            List(
                JField(item,
                JArray(
                    List(
                        JObject(
                            List(
                            JField(foo,JString(1)), 
                            JField(bar,JString(1)))
                        ), 
                        JObject(
                            List(
                            JField(foo,JString(2)), 
                            JField(bar,JString(2))
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
)
```

but if i add a new xml element:

```
<data>
<baz>234</baz>
<item>
    <foo>1</foo>
    <bar>1</bar>
</item>
<item>
    <foo>2</foo>
    <bar>2</bar>
</item>
</data>
```

the result is different regarding the JArray:

```
JObject(
List(
    JField(data,JObject(
        List(
            JField(baz,JString(234)), 
            JField(item,JObject(
                List(
                    JField(foo,JString(1)), 
                    JField(bar,JString(1))
                ))
            ), 
            JField(item,JObject(
                List(
                    JField(foo,JString(2)), 
                    JField(bar,JString(2))
                ))
            )
        )
    ))
)
```

)

The array isn't defined and i have two objects with the name "item". Is this a normal behavior? I would like to have the array without wrapping someting aroung the "item" Tags.

Answer (score 5):

Yep, this is the intended behavior: `net.liftweb.json.Xml` will only group child elements into a `JArray` if they all have the same name. You can try to get around this behavior by manipulating the generated JSON:

```
JObject(
  (json \ "data").asInstanceOf[JObject].obj.groupBy(_.name).map {
    case (_, v :: Nil) => v
    case (k, vs)       => JField(k, JArray(vs.map(_.value)))
  }.toList
)
```

But there are at least a couple of potential problems here:

1. We're using `groupBy`, so we may end up rearranging the order of
   child elements.
2. If there's only one `item`, it won't get wrapped in a `JArray`.

Depending on how much you care, you could write your way around these issues, but it's almost certainly not worth it. Just ignore `net.liftweb.json.Xml` and generate both your XML and your JSON from a Scala data structure.

Comment: How would you do that? create a case class with the fields and than serialize it?

Comment: Yes, that would give you much more control over the representation in both serialization formats.

Comment: please give me an example of `generate both your XML and your JSON from a Scala data structure.`