# How to convert xml array to json data in scala

Tags: xml, json, scala, spray-json

I have the xml data in an array as below, i.e, each line corresponds to a single element in array

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

How to convert this xml array to JSON format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download lift-json jar from http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/net/liftweb/

Be sure to grab the proper library for your Scala version, at time of this post the latest was located at http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/net/liftweb/lift-json_2.8.1⁄2.3-RC5/

```
import net.liftweb.json._
import net.liftweb.json.JsonAST._

val data = xml.XML.loadFile("quotie.xml")
val str = Printer.pretty(render(Xml.toJson(data)))

var out_file = new java.io.FileOutputStream("quotie.json")
var out_stream = new java.io.PrintStream(out_file)

out_stream.print(str)
out_stream.close
```

Comment: But you should know that lift has a bug. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019633/converting-xml-to-json-with-lift-behaves-strange